# Update statement using IN clause issue

Tags: sql, performance, db2, sql-update

I have an update statement that goes thus:

```
update tableA 
    set val1='X', val2='Y' 

where id in (
    select id from tableA A 

    LEFT JOIN tableB B ON A.col1=B.col1 and A.col2=B.col2 

    where A.col3='xx' and B.col3= 'YY')
```

Now, the inner SELECT statement runs in 10 minutes returning 1000 records (both tableA and tableB have about 10mil records each)

The whole update statement runs for 3 hours ( have not waited yet for completion)

Any ideas?

Comment: It is probably running the inner query for every row in tableA.  What database are you using?

Comment: are there any indexes on table A involving the modified columns?  The overhead could be slowing down the process

Comment: Have you separately measured the time to update Val1 and Val2 in 1000 records in Table A without the sub query?  Given that the table has 10,000,000 records, if those columns are indexed or the table has check constraints or a trigger it could possibly simply be the update that's killing you, not the sub query.

Comment: Why do you use LEFT JOIN in the inner query? Later, in the WHERE clause you eliminate these records (B.col3 = 'YY'). Shouldn't it be INNER JOIN ?

Comment: Good suggestion. I will try that to root out the cause.

Answer (score 2):

There is probably no index on the column `tableA.id` or the type of `tableA.id` doesn't match the type returned by the `select`.

[EDIT] Alternatively, you can try this weird syntax:

```
update (
    select val1, val2 from tableA A 

    LEFT JOIN tableB B ON A.col1=B.col1 and A.col2=B.col2 

    where A.col3='xx' and B.col3= 'YY'
) tmp
set val1='X', val2='Y'
```

This creates a temporary table which is still linked to the original table, so you can update the values which the select returns and they will show up in the original table.

[EDIT2] I missed the fact that you're selecting and updating the same table (i.e. `id` is the same column). In this case, the type obviously doesn't matter and you shouldn't even need an index (since the select already returns the correct rows).

Try `EXPLAIN PLAN` to see whether something else is going on.

Also, you might get in conflict with another process which also updates the same table (i.e. you have a lock somewhere). [AQT](http://www.querytool.com/) has a Monitor which can show these things. If you can, get AQT and use that. It has excellent support for DB2 and is better than anything I've seen out there so far.

Comment: +1 -- good call.  Also, you can try an EXPLAIN on your query.

Comment: There is an index on tableA.id
I dont think type of tableA.id concern is valid here.

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is a bit old, but Id like to share what happened to me (specifically today hehe).

We were facing the same problem. Update was taking forever to run!
So we found out that the table we were trying to update was locked. However no error message was thrown by DB2.

hope that Ive had helped somehow!
cheers.
~chamb~

Answer (score 0):

I've had success in the past with breaking the subquery out, and storing its output to a temporary table.  e.g.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE my_ids (id INT);

INSERT INTO my_ids select id from tableA A 

    LEFT JOIN tableB B ON A.col1=B.col1 and A.col2=B.col2 

    where A.col3='xx' and B.col3= 'YY';

update tableA 
    set val1='X', val2='Y' 
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM my_ids);
```

If your specific SQL flavor has some sort of UPDATE JOIN-esque syntax (e.g. UPDATE tableA USING my_ids) that may also be worth trying

Comment: this is indeed a solution but this is a daily batch job and DBAs are not cool with creating these temporary tables.

Comment: You could use global temporary tables, which only exist until the application that declared them ends its connection to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have indexes on any of the columns?  If you don't have indexes on tableA.col1, tableB.col1, tableA.col2, tableB.col2, tableA.col3, and tableB.col3 this could explain the long seek times.  If you don't have indexes for those comparisons, you will be forced to scan over the entire table, which will be slow.

Also, even if you have indexes you should check to see if your statistics are up to date; if they're not, that can cause problems even if the physical structure of the indexes is otherwise fine.

You don't mention the database you're using, but if you have the means to get it to tell you the execution plan of your query, you can use that to determine what it's doing and take appropriate action to add the indexes you'll need.

Answer (score 0):

You should try an update join as this should improve the explain plan.

```
update tableA A, tableB B
set A.val1='X', A.val2='Y' 
where A.col1 = B.col1 and A.col2 = B.col2
  and A.col3 = 'xx' and B.col3 = 'YY'
```

Indexes will clearly help with this join as others have already stated. Please copy the EXPLAIN results if you want us to check that indexes are in use.

Comment: This syntax is not supported in DB2.

Comment: DB2 was not specified when I wrote this.

Answer (score 0):

Others have suggested using EXPLAIN to help identify where the query is slow, which is certainly a good idea.

One other suggestion, although uou don't say what version of DB2 you're using, or what platform it is on:

You might want to try using the MERGE statement, which is the ANSI SQL statement for an update join (this has been available in DB2 for Linux/Unix/Windows since V8.2):

The merge statement would look something like (not tested):

```
merge into tableA a
   using (select id, col1, col2 from tableB where col3 = 'YY') as b
   on (a.col1 = b.col1 and a.col2 = b.col2 and a.col3 = 'xx')
   when matched 
   then update set val1 = 'X', val2 = 'Y'
```